# WebStorm formatting settings - port to another editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, ide, webstorm

Is there any way to get another editor, like VSCode, to format code ( JavaScript in my case, if it matters ) like the WebStorm IDE formats code by default? I'm not familiar with that IDE, but I'm hoping that it uses a config of some sort that can maybe be exported and imported in another editor. I tried looking for one, but couldn't find anything.

The core problem, if it matters, is that all of our team members use WS to write code and they use the built in formatter, so if I use another one it creates inconsistencies and long commits when editing already written files. As you are probably guessing by now, I would like to use another editor, because I find IDE's bloated and slow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to import Webstorm formatting rules into VS Code, but I think there is another solution:

I remember in one of the projects i worked on, we used a linter which also auto-formatted code. The advantage is that Webstorm and VSCode can pick pick the linter rules automatically, and then you have same formatting on both.

The downside is that you would need to agree with the team on what does rule will be and then configure them on the linter.

Comment: That is not an option in my particular case. The situation is, I can use another editor if I can get it to format the code the same way, but none of them actually have to make any changes whatsoever to their workflow, nor should they have to make any changes to their editors or configs. So.. you are free to use whatever you want, but if you cant get it to format the code in the same way, you are pretty much forced to use the same editor everybody else is using.

Comment: In that case I would configure VS Code (or whatever editor I use) to match WebStorm formatting rules. One way to know you got it right is to reformat the entire proyect and check if there were any changes. If there weren't, then both settings match.